# Force Google Distance matrix API to return place_id as address

Tags: android, google-distancematrix-api

I am successfully sending a request to the Google Distance Matrix API with a list of place ids. However, when I get the results, the destination address is a physical address and not the place id that was sent in the request. Is there any way to force the API to return the place id sent as the destination address?

request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=51.048615,-114.070846&destinations=place_id:ChIJgbHj2CN6cVMRPYmSpSbpiTQ|place_id:ChIJZTyyqeFvcVMRF7KgQedMKjA&key=AKEY
```

response:

```
destination_addresses: [
   "5555 76 Ave SE, Calgary, AB T2C 4L8, Canada",
   "834 11 Ave SW, Calgary, AB T2R 0E5, Canada"
]...
```

I am using the Distance Matrix API to build an Android app that finds the nearest few places from a custom list. I have created the model in the application that stores the place id to use for these queries. Since some place ids don't point to the exact establishment (sometimes just to the general area or building) I would like to map the distance results back to the objects using the place id.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify to Google Distance matrix to return place Id instead of physical address. Pass the physical address you got to place API to retrieve the place Id.